# Best format for attaching images in e-mail

Tags: image, email, formats

The subject pretty much says it all. What is the best and most compatible format for attaching or embedding images in an e-mail? GIF, JPG, PNG, SVG, BMP, (etc.)? Are these read by all modern e-mail clients or are there some gotchas we need to watch out for? What about mobile clients (not browser-based)? How about formats that support alpha channels?

Comment: Just about everything supports PNG, and it uses lossless compression and supports alpha channels. For photographs though, JPEG is probably better since it does more (lossy) compression.

Comment: Embedding is a different technique to attaching images. Attaching uses the `<img src="">` tag, while embedding uses something like base64 encoding to avoid having to download an externally hosted image. Here is some [info on embedding](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3927/embedded-images-in-html-email).

Answer (score 1):

PNGs are not supported by older Lotus Notes (6.5, 7). Using alpha transparency and true color might cause problems (e.g. in older Outlook versions). Stay with the good old GIF and JPG and you are safe. And remember that GIF *animations* may (a.) play slow on mobiles and that they may (b.) show only the first frame in some email environments (e.g. Outlook 2007+). I would not rely on vector graphics. However, [here's an interesting example](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/4035/css3-animation-svg-masks-web-fonts-panics-newsletter) that includes a fallback image.

Comment: JPEG is the safest, however you'll probably be fine using PNG, and have the benefit of transparency. From my experience, Lotus notes 6.5-7 users only account for <0.2% of most lists anyway.

Comment: That's true: Lotus Notes is hardly used today. GIF also provides transparency, but the compression does not well on photographic images. FYI: I just had a look at about 9.000 newsletters (http://bit.ly/1kM4zs8) and my suspicion is confirmed: JPG/GIF are by far the most popular image formats in emails.